# Does $f(\frac{x+y}{2})\leqslant \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ imply continuity?

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

Recently I encountered two problems:

Notation: For $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$, where $S\subset \mathbb{R}$, if $f$ is continuous on $S$, then denote $f\in \mathcal{C}(S)$.

> 1. Suppose $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is such that at every point in $(a,b)$ the single side limit of $f$ exists, and that $$f(\frac{x+y}{2})\leqslant \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2},\; \forall x,y \in (a,b).$$ Show that $f\in \mathcal{C}(a,b)$.
> 2. Suppose $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $$f[\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2]\leqslant \lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2),\; \forall x_1,x_2\in (a,b),\forall \lambda \in (0,1).$$ Show that $f\in \mathcal{C}(a,b)$.

I found them a bit alike, and then I came up with the following question:

> Suppose $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is an interval, is such that $$f(\frac{x+y}{2})\leqslant \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2},\; \forall x,y \in I.$$
>   Is it possible that $f\notin \mathcal{C}(I)$?

I've tried both proving and disproving the statement but failed. My guess is a counterexample exists. Please help.

Comment: Every $\Bbb Q$-linear discontinuous function does that last thing you said (in the special case of equality), does it not?

Comment: If I understand it correctly then a counterexample is provided here: http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-discontinuous-midpoint-convex-function/

Comment: This should also do: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/71024/42969

Comment: @MartinR YES! The links do answer my doubt, thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of a function such that $\varphi\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\leq \frac{\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)}{2}$ but $\varphi$ is not convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/example-of-a-function-such-that-varphi-left-fracxy2-right-leq-frac-va) – the provided example is not only not convex, but also not continuous anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is really important that you have the one-sided limits $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$. Let $x>x_0$. Then
$$
f\left(\frac{x+x_0}2\right)\le\frac{f(x)+f(x_0)}2.
$$
Letting $x\to x_0$ yields
$$
f(x_0+)\le\frac{f(x_0+)+f(x_0)}2,
$$
that is, $f(x_0+)\le f(x_0)$. Similarly, you prove that $f(x_0-)\le f(x_0)$. In particular, $f(x_0)\ge\frac{f(x_0+)+f(x_0-)}2$.

On the other hand,
$$
f(x_0) = f\left(\frac{(x_0+\epsilon)+(x_0-\epsilon)}2\right)\le\frac{f(x_0+\epsilon)+f(x_0-\epsilon)}2
$$
and so, letting $\epsilon\to 0$ gives $f(x_0)\le\frac{f(x_0+)+f(x_0-)}2$. Hence,
$$
f(x_0) = \frac{f(x_0+)+f(x_0-)}2
$$
But also (see above) $f(x_0+)\le f(x_0)$ and $f(x_0-)\le f(x_0)$. This yields $f(x_0) = f(x_0+) = f(x_0-)$.

As to 2. see for example here: [Proof every convex function is continuous (Problem 10 Convex Functions Spivak)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660714/proof-every-convex-function-is-continuous-problem-10-convex-functions-spivak)