# Prove that midpoint convex and bounded imply continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity, jensen-inequality

**Question:** Let $f$ be a function on $[a, b]$. For $\forall x\in[a, b], |f(x)|\le M$ where $M>0$, and for $\forall x, y\in[a, b], f(\frac{x+y}{2})\le\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$.

> (1) Prove that $f$ is continuous on $(a, b)$.
>
> (2) Must $f$ be continuous at $a$ and $b$, respectively?

*Note* that I already checked the answer in:

[Does $f(\frac{x+y}{2})\leqslant \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ imply continuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3407135/745329)

[Example of a function such that $\varphi\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\leq \frac{\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)}{2}$ but $\varphi$ is not convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71019/745329)

[Midpoint-Convex and Continuous Implies Convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83383/745329)

but none of them helped. The answer in the first one is not a precise solution I think. He(or she) put $x_0+\delta (\delta>0)$ as $x_0+$ and regarded $x_0+\delta /2(\delta>0)$ as $x_0+$, which is non-sense. So, it was quite weird to me.

I knew that without the condition that $f$ is bounded, we cannot say that $f$ is convex (or continuous). Instead, when $f$ is continuous unless $f$ is bounded, then $f$ is convex. (This is actually not a key point of this problem, I think; just interesting stuff)

The closest solution was in:

[Proof every convex function is continuous (Problem 10 Convex Functions Spivak)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2660714/745329)

They took account of the general form of Jensen's Inequality, but in this problem, we only have to deal with $\lambda=1/2$. I tried in an analogous way, but I stuck:

For $\forall  x, y\in [a, b]$, let $z$ be in $[a, b]$ such that $y=\frac{x+z}{2}$. Substituting $x=x, y=z$ will bring $$f(y)=f(\frac{x+z}{2})\le \frac{f(x)+f(z)}{2}= f(x)+\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{2}$$
$$f(y)-f(x)\le{1\over2}(f(z)-f(x))\le{1\over2}(M-(-M))\le M$$

I do want to make the form $f(y)-f(x)\le K|y-x|$, which implies $f$ is Lipschitz continuous(and of course, continuous on $[a, b]$; we can prove this by setting $\delta=\epsilon/K$. But I failed to make such a form.

Could you give me some hints or other ideas to the problem? Thanks.

(+) I think there are many counterexamples of (b).

Comment: For the first answer, he doesn't denote $x_0+$ to be a number, he defines
$f(x_0+)$ as $lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)$.

Maybe it is confusing since it looks like you are evaluating $f$ at some number $x_0+$, but it's not. Maybe he should've used the notation $f^+(x_0)$. Although in that case they were assuming the one sided limits to exist.

Comment: @JulianMejia I see, but isn't that appying $f^+(x_0)$ directly to the condition $f(\frac{x+y}{2})\le\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ weird?

Comment: For a counter-example in (2) let $ M'=\sup \{f(x):x\in (a,b)\}$ and let $f(a)=f(b)=M'+1=M.$